# Calling web service over SSL Domain Name

Tags: web-services, iis, ssl, ssl-certificate, iis-8

Hey all i seem to be having problems with calling my web service over SSL. Calling it from a non-ssl URL works just fine.

When trying to connect to the web service in VB.net it gives me this:

[image: ws]

So i go ahead and choose the first option (10/7/2012 to 10/7/2013.

However when i do that i get this error in the web browser:

[image]

Going to the SSL website of mine (https://www.xxxxxxx.com) asks the same question (Select a Certificat) and then it shows the same browser error as it did in VB.net.

Is there something i need to include in the web.config file?

My IIS certificates look like this that i created:

[image]

Going to my normal website (http://www.xxxxxxx.com) works just fine.

What have i forgotten to do in order for it to work over SSL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likly you've likley over-configured IIS (unless you really want to use SSL with client authentication as noted by Arun).

There is setting somewhere that says something "require client certificate:none/accept/require" which defaults to none for regular SSL. The only place you needed to add certificate is in site bindings...

Side note: http://serverfault.com could be better place...

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using SSL with client authentication .. Make sure you have added the CA certificate and the user certificate[that u choose in the prompt] to the user's list in the server before trying to access the website . I know how to do this in apache but not IIS but the concept is the same.